# regular expression in java matcher pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I would like to ask the java regular expression in Matcher & Pattern

my code is

```
Pattern TR = Pattern.compile("\\\\[\+"\\\\]T\\\\[MR\\\\]");
```

I'm looking for the rgx for

```
+TR
"TR
+TM
"TM
```

There is something wrong on my regular expression. Could someone please point out ? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the below would be enough for your case.

```
Pattern TR = Pattern.compile("[+\"]T[MR]");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sV8yT8/3)

`[+\"]` - Character class which matches double quotes or `+` symbol.

`[MR]` - Matches `M` or `R` character.

`\"` - Matches the literal double quotes.

**Example:**

```
String[] s = {"+TR","\"TR","+TM","\"TM"};
for (String i:s)
{
 System.out.println(i.matches("[+\"]T[MR]"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
true
```

Comment: Thanks, I though I need escape from [    and     ].